# Как показывать данные таблицы, в зависимости от роли пользователя?

Tags: php

Есть страница с таблицей в которой выводятся товары, и есть несколько пользователей, скажем: админ, модер, и редактор

В зависимости от роли юзера выводиться таблица, например : https://codepen.io/5h4dy_s/pen/jOMrXoW

Сначала пробовал сделать шблоны таблиц для каждого юзера: проверял и выдавал нужный, но этот вариант мне не очень понравился.
Так же пробовал делать проверку:

```
if($user_role == 'admin') { echo ' <th>Себестоимость</th>'; }
```

Но этот вариант еще хуже чем предыдущий.
Каким образом, я могу реализовать это, максимально правильно, ибо все что приходит в голову это костыли, которые я описал выше ? Прошу знающих дать совет как лучше это сделать.

Comment: Чем отличаются выводимые данные у разных пользователей?

Comment: @InDevX , к примеру: для админа выводить в таблице себе стоимость, а для редактора нет

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/company/custis/blog/248649/ и https://packagist.org/packages/laminas/laminas-permissions-rbac

Comment: @ArchDemon , Спасибо за ссылки